# "PhotoImage Error " object has no attribute PhotoImage error When using with class and Object

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, libraries, python-module

I am working on project named **Color detection** in python using OOPs concept.In this project user have to input an image either by choosing it from system or take photo from web cam.
I almost completed the project but get an runtime error.
Here is my block of code :

```
self.root = Tk()
....
....
self.capture_frame = Frame(self.root, width=750, height=550, bg='black')
....
....

def openCamera(self,capture_frame):
    self.hide_all_frames()
    self.capture_frame.pack()
    
    #button
    snapshot_btn = Button(capture_frame,text="CAPTURE",width=13, bg = '#1cbab5',
                          fg = 'black',font = ('dsrom 10',12,'bold'),command = self.snapshot).place(x=170,y=515)
    
    BACK_btn = Button(capture_frame,text="BACK",width=13, bg = 'red',
                      fg = 'black',font = ('dsrom 10',12,'bold'),
                      command = lambda :self.firstFrame(self.image_selection_frame)).place(x=400,y=515)
    
    #Labels
    self.cam_area = Label(capture_frame, bg = 'black')
    self.cam_area.place(x=50,y=20)  
    
    self.cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
    
    #while to open camra 
    while True:
        self.img = self.cap.read()[1]
        self.img = cv.flip(self.img,1)
        self.img1 = cv.cvtColor(self.img,cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = PIL.Image.fromarray(self.img1))
        self.cam_area['image'] = self.img
        self.root.update()

    self.cap.release()
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

This code is working fine when run as separately without creating any function or method.
When i try to include it in my project it run fine, even it capture image and save it in system.
but by the time when I wanted to close the camra and try to reopen it it gives a error :

```
[ WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-j6tkfxml/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (893) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index
Exception in Tkinter callback

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "/home/safehouse/Desktop/ColorDetection.py", line 145, in <lambda>
font = ('dsrom 10',10,'bold'),command=lambda 
:self.capturecmd(self.capture_frame)).place(x=450,y=130)
File "/home/safehouse/Desktop/ColorDetection.py", line 205, in capturecmd
self.img1 = cv.cvtColor(self.img,cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) /tmp/pip-req-build-j6tkfxml/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'
```

**When I capture then close the application without restarting the camera I get the following error**

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
  return self.func(*args)
File "/home/safehouse/Desktop/ColorDetection.py", line 145, in <lambda>
  font = ('dsrom 10',10,'bold'),command=lambda 
:self.capturecmd(self.capture_frame)).place(x=450,y=130)
File "/home/safehouse/Desktop/ColorDetection.py", line 206, in capturecmd
   self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(master = self.cam_area,image = Image.fromarray(self.img1))
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 112, in 
__init__
   self.__photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(**kw)
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 4064, in __init__
   Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 4009, in __init__
   self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_   tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "image" command: application has been destroyed
Exception ignored in: <function PhotoImage.__del__ at 0x7f866f265ca0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 118, in __del__
   name = self.__photo.name
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'
```

**when I use root = tk() I get the Photoimage() attribute error but when i use**

```
root = Toplevel()
```

**I get rid of the above photoimage error but then i got new error :**

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
  return self.func(*args)
File "/home/safehouse/Desktop/ColorDetection.py", line 145, in <lambda>
  font = ('dsrom 10',10,'bold'),command=lambda :self.capturecmd(self.capture_frame)).place(x=450,y=130)
File "/home/safehouse/Desktop/ColorDetection.py", line 207, in capturecmd
  self.cam_area['image'] = self.img
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1657, in __setitem__
  self.configure({key: value})
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1646, in configure
  return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1636, in _configure
  self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!toplevel.!frame3.!label"
```

This much I had tried and search everywhere and try using different version packages but non of then really work.
All my project is working fine and camera is also taking photo and saving it. But due the the above errors, I was unable to restart camera without closing the whole project. And due to Photoimage error, it remove the camera screen.

**If anyone can help , it will be a great help.**

Comment: How many `tkinter.Tk()` windows do you have? If it is more than 1, you should be passing in the `master` argument when creating the `PhotoImage`.

Comment: The function name `self.capturecmd` in the error traceback is not the same as the posted code.

Comment: Two tkinter windows, and already tried passing the master argument , but it doesn't work , 
I renamed the function here so that it can easily be understood.

Comment: @RohitRaj You must pass in the `master` argument. Also the `cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1)` error isn't a `tkinter` error.

Comment: master = ????
what should be pass in master argument ,
root or frame ??? I had tried both but still got that "PhotoImage attribute" error.
and then what to do with cv2.error. this error crash the whole application.